# HttpWebResponse().GetResponse Timed out

Tags: c#, api, rms

I'm trying to get my program to talk to an API using the `HttpWebRequest`/`Response`. The POST call works and generates an auth code.

The second call I'm making is a GET call and for some reason it times out every time. I've tried `Request.Timeout`, `.readwritetimeout`, `content type`, `servicepoint` and `protocolVersion` with no success.

This is my code:

```cs
public void InHouseReservations()
{
    try
    {
        int Id = 0;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{Properties.Settings.Default.RMSAPIIp}reservations/inHouse?modelType=basic&propertyId=1");
        //request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add($"authtoken: {RMSAuthToken}");
        request.Timeout = 200000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 200000;

        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            }

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic tokenJSON = JObject.Parse(responseString);
            ReservationID = tokenJSON.Id;
            response.Close();
        }

           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you validated that it's not just the API being stuck, never returning any response?

Comment: Does the api support get requests?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy yeah, the api documentation shows that the url im using is a GET call

Comment: @FranzGleichmann im a little unsure what you mean by this, when my code runs it just gets stuck at the response part and eventually says "the operation timed out"

Comment: @jlfish1997 Did you try to issue the same request with Postman? Does it succeed?

Comment: @PeterCsala same error, a timeout has occured

Comment: @jlfish1997 Then the problem is not in your code.